# In I2C bus, how slave devices knows data belongs to them or not

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

I have one micro controller and 4 slave devices are attached with micro controller I2C bus. I have one doubt regarding data reading from I2C bus. When master initiates any transmission it will write device address on the I2C bus, but i want to know how slave devices will identify in I2C bus, data belongs to them or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slave devices have an address, either a fixed one or often an address where one or two bits can be configured by hardware (pulling certain pins of the chip to ground or VCC). Each slave knows its own address.

The slaves listen to all I2C communication. If an I2C transaction contains their address at the start, they will interact in the transaction. Otherwise they will ignore the transaction.